# How to display data in different rows when joining two tables

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 Temp. tables that look something like this

`@t1(p_ssn,p_fname,p_lname,Gender,.............)`  -> this table has the employee records and has about **30 columns**

`@t2(p_ssn,benefit,medical_premium,dental_premium,..............)` -> this table  has the employee benefits and has about **60 columns**

Every record in `@t1` will have 1 or more corresponding records in `@t2`

How do I do a join between the tables to get a display like this (join on p_ssn)
I want the each employee record, followed by all their benefits records- **each on a different line as shown**

```
p_fname,p_lname,Gender etc...      -> 1st employee
benefit1,medical_premium1,dental_premium_1     -> all the benefit records for this employee
p_fname,p_lname,Gender etc...      -> 2nd  employee
benefit1,medical_premium1,dental_premium_1
```

Right now, I am using a loop. But due to the large size of the each record, it just hangs up after going halfway through.

---

@Tim - This is where I am stuck. @t1 has only 30 columns, but @t2 has 60 columns

-- Actual query

```
    select col1, col2 from 
(     -- Get employees     
 select 10 as ordinal, p_ssn, p_fname as col1, p_lname as col2,**there are only 30 columns here**     
 from @t1     
union all    
 -- Get benefits     
select 20 as ordinal, a.p_ssn, cast(b.benefit as varchar(50)), cast(b.premium as varchar(50)) ,**I want to display more columns here like b.col1,b.col2,b.col3 etc...60 columns**    
from @t1 a         
 join @t2 b on a.p_ssn = b.p_ssn ) as a order by p_ssn, ordinal
```

I know that I can do the following

```
  select 10 as ordinal, p_ssn, p_fname as col1, p_lname as col2,'','',''
from @t1
 union all
select 20 as ordinal, a.p_ssn, cast(b.benefit as varchar(50)), cast(b.premium as varchar(50)),b.col1,b.col2,n.col3
```

But this is a file feed and blanks are not allowed. In fact, I wont be able to use the cast because the lenghths and data types are defined and cannot be changed

Comment: Note that it's not really the job of a query to return the results exactly the way they are to be displayed. When issuing a query, you are querying for *data*, not for their *look*. It's the presentation layer that should take care of how the data are *presented* to the user.

Comment: Please specify us the format of the output file.  Fixed width or delimiters, # of cols, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might end up doing something like this:

```
-- Setup demo data
declare @t1 table (
      p_ssn char(11) not null primary key
    , p_fname varchar(50) not null
    , p_lname varchar(50) not null
)
insert into @t1 select '000-00-0000', 'Joe', 'Blow'
insert into @t1 select '111-11-1111', 'Jane', 'Doe'
declare @t2 table (
      p_ssn char(11) not null
    , benefit varchar(50)
    , premium int
)
insert into @t2 select '000-00-0000', 'Benefit 1', 100
insert into @t2 select '000-00-0000', 'Benefit 2', 200
insert into @t2 select '111-11-1111', 'Benefit 1', 300
insert into @t2 select '111-11-1111', 'Benefit 2', 400

-- Actual query
select col1, col2
from (
    -- Get employees
    select 10 as ordinal, p_ssn, p_fname as col1, p_lname as col2
    from @t1
    union all
    -- Get benefits
    select 20 as ordinal, a.p_ssn, cast(b.benefit as varchar(50)), cast(b.premium as varchar(50))
    from @t1 a
        join @t2 b on a.p_ssn = b.p_ssn
) as a
order by p_ssn, ordinal
```

To get an output like this:

```
col1        col2
Joe         Blow
Benefit 1   100
Benefit 2   200
Jane        Doe
Benefit 1   300
Benefit 2   400
```

The trick is generating that `ordinal` column that we can sort by later.

I would normally advise against creating reports like this in the database engine, however, as that's what reporting tools and front-end code on your web/app servers is for (these often scale better).  Also, be careful of the use of [SSN as a primary key](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/primarykey.htm).

Comment: The problem with the above is that I cannot use UNION ALL because the the Employee and the Benefits tables are totally different with different number of fields. What I wrote was just a sample

Comment: Interesting. I would think that as long as you select the same number of columns (not `select *`) and cast to the same datatypes, you should be able to union. Are you looking to get more columns in the query?

Comment: The table t1 has around 60 columns while t2 around 35 columns. So I will have to select blank columns in t2 to do the union. This is not what i want

Comment: I guess I don't really understand this problem. Could you edit your question to more clearly illustrate what you want?

Comment: Appreciate all your help. I have edited and added a note to the end of my Question.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is your output is concatenated fields(e.g. p_lname + ', ' + p_fname). This might be a possible solution:

```
declare @tmpResult table(GroupRankNo int
                        , Name nvarchar(100)
                        , Benefits nvarchar(500)
                        , SSN int)

insert into @tmpResult table(GroupRankNo
                            , Name
                            , Benefits
                            , SSN)
select row_number() over(partition by aa.Name order by aa.Name) as GroupRankNo
        , aa.Name
        , aa.Benefits
        , aa.p_ssn
from
(       
    select a.p_fname + ', ' + a.p_lname as Name
            , b.benefit + ', ' + b.premium as Benefits
            , a.p_ssn
    from @t1 a
    inner join @t2 b on b.p_ssn = a.p_ssn
) aa                                


select aa.ColumnData
from
(
    select SSN
            , Name as ColumnData
            , 0 as RowType --Header
    from @tmpResult
    where GroupRankNo = 1

    union

    select SSN
            , Benefits as ColumnData
            , 1 as RowType --Detail
    from @tmpResult
) aa
order by aa.SSN
            , RowType asc
```

I haven't tested it. But you'll get the idea, using the "row_number() over partition by"

Comment: Thanks for thr reply. Please see the comment that I added at the end of my Question for @Tim. I will be having the same problem with the UNION in your above query.

Comment: Seems like a file feed. What should be the format of the file? Concatenating the fields into 1 field might work for you as long as you know the delimiter you need. In that case, you wouldn't have a problem with the 'union'.

Comment: Thats a good idea - Never thought about concatenating the fields. Thanks.I will try it out